# Layout not showing properly on 7" tablets(Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I developed an android application with reference to Nexus 7 in android studio preview which is 7" in size. The app is running with designed layout in some 7" tablets but not running with desired layouts in some other 7" tablets.

[![Display with layout being mixed up (iball Slide 7" tablet)][1]][1]. 
[![Dispay with proper layout(Micromax canvas P290 )][2]][2]

This is the xml code for layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chek"
    android:background="@drawable/border_around"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/patient">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Date                 :"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
        android:text="2/11/2016"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:id="@+id/viewa"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateTxt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewa"
        android:text="IP No                            :"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/idTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id"
        android:text="133245"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:id="@+id/viewb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idTxt"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/patientName"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Patient Name   :"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/patientNameTxt"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/patientName"
        android:text="Ravi Kumar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/docName"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewa"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Primary Consultant     :"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/docNameTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/docName"
        android:text="fddf"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewb"
        android:text="Age           :"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ageTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/age"
        android:text="48"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bednum"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/age"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewb"
        android:text="Bed No     :"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bednumTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bednum"
        android:text="14"
        android:layout_below="@id/age"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/patient"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"

            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bed"
                android:id="@+id/dailyassesment"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nursingassessment"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Handover Checklist"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/nursingassesment"
                android:id="@+id/nursingcare"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doctor"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nursing Care Plans"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nursingassessment"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line3">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/graph"
                android:id="@+id/vitalsigns"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nursingassessment"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vital Signs Input"
                android:layout_below="@+id/vitalsigns"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/line3"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line2">-->
            <!--<ImageView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="180dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:src="@drawable/nursecare"-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/nursingassessment"-->
                <!--android:clickable="true"-->
                <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doctor"-->
                <!--/>-->
            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:text="Nursing Initial Assesments"-->
                <!--android:layout_below="@+id/nursingassessment"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>-->
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/line5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line4">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/doctor"
                android:id="@+id/doctor"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Doctors Notes"
                android:layout_below="@+id/doctor"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/line6"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line4"

            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bed"
                android:id="@+id/dailyassesment1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nursingassessment"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ISBAR Checklist-GW"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/line7"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line4"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bed"
                android:id="@+id/dailyassesment2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nursingassessment"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ISBAR-ICU"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: nexus 7 has 2 version. 2012 version has 800p resolution where 2013 has 1080p resolution. Check your version and the other 7' tab resolution. Size doesn't matter, screen resolution matters.

Comment: I am using android studio 2.1.2.I don't know which version of nexus 7 is showing in that? How can I design for 7 inch tablets which suits diff screen resolution.

Comment: Nexus 7 = 2013 , Nexus 7 (2012) = 2012 version.  anyways `use width="0dp"` and `layout_weight` property to fit  all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library for working with multiple screen resolutions it is easy to use and simply documented with sample code [source](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your scrollview with the following code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dailyassesment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Handover Checklist"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nursingcare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Nursing Care Plans"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vitalsigns"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Vital Signs Input"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/doctor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/doctor"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Doctors Notes"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dailyassesment1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ISBAR Checklist-GW"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dailyassesment2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ISBAR-ICU"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Note: Replace your images... I am adding default launcher icons**

Comment: @amsheer..Now also I am having different layouts in 2 tablets

Comment: What you have done added inside of scrollview right? what is happening now?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! scrollview will fit all sizes!! for the upper section you need to create seprated layout for different sizes! You can do it from the top menu in the designer page in android studio "create other variation"    or manage it programmatically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chek"
            android:background="@drawable/delete"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/patient">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Date                 :"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                android:text="2/11/2016"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:id="@+id/viewa"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewa"
                android:text="IP No                            :"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/idTxt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id"
                android:text="133245"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:id="@+id/viewb"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idTxt"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/patientName"
                android:layout_below="@id/date"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Patient Name   :"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/patientNameTxt"
                android:layout_below="@id/date"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/patientName"
                android:text="Ravi Kumar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/docName"
                android:layout_below="@id/date"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewa"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Primary Consultant     :"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/docNameTxt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/date"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/docName"
                android:text="fddf"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewb"
                android:text="Age           :"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ageTxt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/age"
                android:text="48"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bednum"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/age"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewb"
                android:text="Bed No     :"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bednumTxt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bednum"
                android:text="14"
                android:layout_below="@id/age"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/patient"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/firstRow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/line1"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/delete"
                        android:id="@+id/dailyassesment"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nursingassessment" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Handover Checklist"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"
                        android:gravity="center" />


                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/line3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/delete"
                        android:id="@+id/nursingcare"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Nursing Care Plans"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/line4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/delete"
                        android:id="@+id/vitalsigns"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Vital Signs Input"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/line3"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line2">-->
                <!--<ImageView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="180dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:src="@drawable/nursecare"-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/nursingassessment"-->
                <!--android:clickable="true"-->
                <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doctor"-->
                <!--/>-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:text="Nursing Initial Assesments"-->
                <!--android:layout_below="@+id/nursingassessment"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"/>-->
                <!--</LinearLayout>-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/secondRow"
                    android:layout_below="@id/firstRow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/line5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/delete"
                        android:id="@+id/doctor"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Doctors Notes"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/doctor"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/line6"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/delete"
                        android:id="@+id/dailyassesment1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ISBAR Checklist-GW"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:gravity="center" />


                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/line7"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/delete"
                        android:id="@+id/dailyassesment2"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ISBAR-ICU"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:gravity="center" />


                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>
```